# What is the meaning of $\mathrm{d}^4k$ in this integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, integration, calculus

From Gerardus 't Hooft's Nobel Lecture, December 8, 1999, he states the following equation (2.1):

$$
\int \mathrm{d}^4k \frac{\operatorname{Pol}(k_{\mu})}{(k^2+m^2)\bigl((k+q)^2+m^2\bigr)}  =  \infty
$$

in relation to weak interactions theory, where $\operatorname{Pol}(k_{\mu})$ stands for some polynomial in the integration variables $k_{\mu}$, and then goes on to say that physically it must be a nonsense.

Why is it a nonsense?

What sort of integral is this, and how does one interpret it?

Is the $\mathrm{d}^4k$ shorthand for 4th degree integration?

At what stage and subject of a physics course does one learn about it (A pre-fresher is asking)?

Comment: Have you tried to look this up? It seems like you already have some idea of what it means, and the resources to understand more are definitely out there. Also, this kind of seems like a mathematical question to me; other than the mere fact that you saw it in the context of physics, I don't think there's much of any physics in this question.

Comment: $d^4k = dk_0 dk_1 dk_2 dk_3$

Comment: Where e.g. $k_0 = k_{\mu=0}$ etc

Comment: @DavidZ, should i delete or ask for migration to Maths.SE, or delete and post to Maths.SE?

Comment: We never _require_ people to delete their questions. If you want to leave the question as is and see what happens, that's totally fine. (Maybe other people will like it more than I do.) But if you do want to retract the question here and post it on [math.SE], I'd say go ahead and do it yourself - delete it here, and then post a version there that is reworded to clearly focus on the math and not on the physics. Migration is more meant for when we close a question as off topic here and want to give it a second chance on another site.

Comment: @innisfree, do the $k_{\mu}$'s stand for a coordinate system and time, eg, 3D Cartesian or spherical?

Comment: @DavidZ, if I'm bleeding rep points, that's the implication

Comment: I think the first two questions are alright here. The last one is probably *opinion based* (I've got a PhD and haven't ever taken a course in QFT, but I'm aware of some undergrads who've taken it), but a [similar question was asked some time ago](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48053) that might help you answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is a term in the calculation of a scattering probability. Obviously a scattering probability must be between zero and one, like any other type of probability. So when the calculation of a scattering probability returns a value of $\infty$ that isn't physically possible, and it shows that the method we are using to calculate the probability is incorrect.

That is what 't Hooft means by *nonsense* - it means the method of doing the calculation is wrong. His Nobel prize was earned showing us the correct way to do the calculation.

The parameter $k$ is a wave vector, or more precisely [the special relativistic form of a wave vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector#In_special_relativity). This is a 4D vector so it has four independant components normally written as $k^0$, $k^1$, $k^2$ and $k^3$. Note that the superscript is a label and doesn't mean you're raising $k$ to a power. The integration is over all possible values of each of the four components, so it's really four integrations:

$$ \int \int \int \int\,dk^0 \,dk^1 \,dk^2 \,dk^3 $$

Writing $d^4k$ is a common shorthand for this.

You are unlikely to study quantum field theory in any depth unless you do a postgraduate course in physics, though I guess some universities may offer it as a final year option.